# How to call a Variable into file-path and print the output in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call a variable into file-path but i'm unable to get it.

file-path mean is  = "`/sys/class/net/bond0/speed`" , where "`bond0`" is dynamic.

In the below code , the `Current_inf` is producing the values like "`bond0`" etc its changeable.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import netifaces
>>> import socket
>>> import re

>>> Current_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
>>> print Current_inf
bond0.180
>>> subprocess.Popen(str['/sys/class/net/%s%s'(Current_inf)/speed])
```

> Below is the shell command what i'm trying to achieve via python

```
# cat /sys/class/net/bond0/speed
2000
```

any help or suggestions will much appreciated.

Comment: `speed = subprocess.check_output('/sys/class/net/%s/speed' % (Current_inf)).rstrip()`. should the `.180` suffix be removed?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no `.180` is there.

Comment: so you want `cat /sys/class/net/bond0.180/speed` ?

Comment: GENERATING AN ERROR : `python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to my original Question:

```
subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/sys/class/net/{}/speed'.format(Current_inf)])
```

oR

```
open('/sys/class/net/{}/speed' .format(Current_inf)).read().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `Popen`, you need `check_output` to get the result directly.

Second, you're trying to convert a `list` in `str` (not sure since `str[...]` is not valid syntax). Drop `str`

Third, that's not how you format a string using `%` (you could also use `str.format`, which is even better)

My proposal:

```
speed = subprocess.check_output('/sys/class/net/%s/speed' % (Current_inf)).rstrip()
```

Upon successful execution, `speed` holds the return value minus the trailing linefeed (thanks to `rstrip()`)

Comment: thnx for your explaination but i need to have `bond0.180` as it has the value with that name.

Comment: I wasn't sure. Edited. But you seem to have problems with that command line.

Comment: looks like there is some permission issue as it throws `python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)` , though via shell command it looks good.

Comment: as i am using the file "` cat /sys/class/net/bond0/speed`"  to get the ouput from but the "`bond0`" part is varying hence it could be "`bond0.180`" or "`eth0`" etc, thus i'm getting that value from "` Current_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]`"  hence  **Current_inf** is a variable which i'm looking to call every-time.

What Will be right approach to call the variable to get the output.